# What do these VM options do?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For an assignment I had to edit the VM options of a Java project in Intellij. The following line had to be added to the options:

```
-Djava.compiler=NONE -DXint
```

However, I have no clue what these options do, so I'm asking it here. I was not able to find anything online about this.

Comment: Do note that flags only have meaning in the right Java version e.g. a flag introduced in Java 9 won't have any effect in Java 8.

Comment: First read, what D parameters are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag `-Djava.compiler=NONE` disables Just-In-Time (JIT)-compilation, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457405/how-to-check-if-the-jit-compiler-is-off-in-java/11463834#11463834).

The flag `-DXint` runs the JVM in interpreted mode, i.e. bytecode is interpreted, never compiled to machine code, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457405/how-to-check-if-the-jit-compiler-is-off-in-java/9457691#9457691).